# Custom View Constructor not called

Tags: android, imageview

i have created CircleImageView to display the image at Circle Shape

**CircularImageView**

```
public class CircularImageView extends ImageView {

private final static String TAG = "CircularImageView";
private final static float DEFAULT_RADIUS = 90;
private float mRadius;

public CircularImageView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public CircularImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public CircularImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);

    TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.CircularImageView,defStyle,0);
    mRadius = a.getFloat(R.styleable.CircularImageView_Radius,DEFAULT_RADIUS);
    //Log.i(TAG, String.format("%f", mRadius));
    a.recycle();


}


@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    Path path = new Path();

    path.addCircle(getWidth() / 2 ,getHeight() / 2,mRadius,Path.Direction.CW);
    canvas.clipPath(path);
    super.onDraw(canvas);
}
```

}

now i am using it inside XML File

**XML File**

```
           xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

            <com.itzik.samara.apps.pokerbuddies.main.back.views.CircularImageView
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:src="@drawable/empty_user_image"
            app:Radius="50"
            android:id="@+id/poker_row_user_image" />
```

**attrs.xml**

```
    <declare-styleable name="CircularImageView">
    <attr name="Radius" format="float" />
</declare-styleable>
```

first Android Studio says Constructor not used??
second it doesn't display the image.
if i change in the function onDraw(Canvas canvas) mRadius to a number the image works meaning onDraw() is called

anyone ever encountered with that kind of problem why the Constructor not called?

Comment: add Log.d in your constructors

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Modify this constructor:

```
public CircularImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}
```

To:

```
public CircularImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    //super(context, attrs);

    this(context, attrs, 0);
}
```

Comment: WOW Thnx didnt think about that one